# android getSystemService(String s) - reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

My question concerns the android development. I would like to know if the method `context.getSystemService(String s)` uses **reflection**. There 
are many `static` `String` constants defined within the `Context` class. I'm not sure how the mechanism behind this method works. Thats why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#910), it seems like it just checks what the value of `s` is, using `equals()` and returns an appropriate value.
So, no Reflection there.

Comment: There is some more code in `Activity` but it works the same way.

Comment: Yeah, it basically just checks that there is a context and then calls the super method: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

There will not be any reflection use it any way